# Rudimentary tools (and process) for reshaping a small piece of steel?

Tags: repair, metal

Hello all and thanks in advance for reading.

I have an old craftsman woodchipper, with small breaker plates that the blades have to fit between when spinning. A blade bent, smashed into 2 of the little metal ridges on the breaker plates, warping and bending the metal.

Blade was repaired by a local mechanic, but I can’t find anyone to fix these pieces, which are preventing the blades from spinning.

I’ve got a clamp and a worktable in the garage, and a willingness to try and heat it up and bend myself. Tolerances are not very tight. What do I need?[image]

Comment: What do you need to do to get them back to usable? If the metal is completely fractured, then without a welder, I wouldn't recommend trying to repair them. Can you find replacement parts?

Comment: The maker's service parts division should be able to help you out.  It's a wearing item, obviously.

Comment: To Ganti and Harper: parts are no longer manufactured, due to age of the model. I suppose I could try and call, but the website is saying they don’t make them, don’t have them in stock. Also checked eBay and one of my favorites, repairclinic.com. You never know, though. A phone call might get me to someone else thy does make them.

Answer (score 1):

First off I wouldn't heat it, it's not that thick and heating it may mess it up. Basically your going to have to get creative. You'll need a vise, clamp it in the vise. If you need to flatten an area put it on a flat spot of the vise and hit it with the hammer. If you need to open it up use a vise grip to bend it open. Search on youtube for "hammer and dolly" for techniques on bending. [These tools](https://www.harborfreight.com/body-and-fender-set-7-pc-63259.html) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that part ,it prevents large pieces from being thrown out. If so, it is only cold rolled steel ,not heat treated so you can heat it. I have a 25 year old Craftsman shredder; I have operated it with that part removed to permit maximum throughput. It will throw a chunk of wood 50 feet so you may not be in a place where that is acceptable. I had room , it actually blasted a patch of ground clear of all weeds, left bare ground. I am sure EPA or OSHA or some other agency would put me in jail if they knew. I am not recommending removal but the machine runs fine without it.